# How to redirect get methods with Liberator in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, liberator

I have an endpoint called `/account` which provides user info(returns html).

When unauthorised user tries to access this endpoint I need to be able to redirect to `login page` but in Liberator I found `post-redirect` so far and it is just for `post methods`.

I need to redirect `get methods` as well, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround following code does the trick:

```
(defn account
  []
  (resource :allowed-methods [:get]

            :available-media-types ["text/html"]

            :exists? (fn [_] false)

            :existed? (fn [_] true)

            :moved-temporarily? (fn [ctx] {:location "/redirected-path-or-url"})

            :handle-ok (fn [ctx]
                         [:html ...])

            :handle-exception (fn [_]
                                "Something went wrong")))
```

Or you can check `:authorized?` and return login html from `:handle-unauthorized` but I doubt it about it's a good practice or not.

Comment: Philipp commented on an old blog post of mine where I also struggled with the exact same problem. He wrote: "to force a redirection on a get request you need to return false from :exists? When you think about it, it actually makes sense. Then you can implement :moved-permanently? or :moved-temporarily? and associate the new location in the context at :location". So, your workaround is actually the official way to do this.

Comment: No need to wrap `false` and `true` in a function. You can use the literal values true: `:exists? false` will work.